# Django form initial data being set as lists

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I am trying to set some initial form data with request.GET data when it's being initialized:

GET data:

```
http://localhost:8000/form_builder/SoW/create/?project=1&value=100
```

The form:

```
class SoWForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SoW
        fields = (
            'project',
            'ref',
            'date_signed',
            'sow_file',
            'value',
            'status'
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SoWForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
```

Initialization of the form:

```
form = SoWForm(initial=request.GET)
```

What happens is that all form fields that are being set are being populated as lists:

[image: form initial fields are populated as lists]

and it breaks the form of course:

[image: broken form data]

Is there a way to avoid this? Does it dict(request.GET) somewhere on the way while trying to pick up the data and stuff?

`dict(request.GET.iteritems())` will convert `request.GET` to a 'proper' dict for the initial data, but isn't default behavior wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the form, but with what you're using to populate it. QueryDicts are a special dict subclass intended to support the possibility of multiple values in the querystring or POST data, for example:

```
>>> QueryDict('a=1&b=2&b=3')
<QueryDict: {u'a': [u'1'], u'b': [u'2', u'3']}>
```

and, as you've discovered, that's not suitable for use as form initial data.

You've already found the workaround; I recommend you continue doing that.